# Is it possible to export the result of "import * as" in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

In ES2015, it's possible to import an entire module as an object whose properties are the module's exports:

```
import * as name from 'module';
```

I find this to be extraordinarily useful for namespacing and use it all the time.

It's also possible to re-export other modules' exports:

```
export { name } from 'module'; // selectively
export * from 'other-module'; // indiscriminately
```

Now I'm trying to write a library with namespacing in this style. The intuitive way of collecting everything in the top-level module would be like this:

```
export * as name from 'module';
```

But that doesn't seem to work; Babel and Rollup both reject it.

I *could* import the module as an object, create a clone by iterating over its keys, and export that, but then it would just be a plain old dynamic object, so I would lose the great advantages Rollup provides.

So, is there *really* no way to do this with the declarative module syntax? It seems to me like there's no excuse for that.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with `export * as name from 'module';`. How would you be planning to use such an export? Importing `*` always requires the namespace `as X`, so whatever name you specify in the export statement would be irrelevant anyway--right?

Comment: @torazaburo `name` is the name the module object is exported with. For instance, if module "abc" contains `export * as xyz from 'xyz'`, and you `import * as abc from 'abc'`, you'll be able to access "xyz"s exports via `abc.xyz`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 module syntax: is it possible to `export * as Name from …`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44640696/1048572)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, this was simply missed in ES6. There [is a stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from) to add these, though, and [rollup will consider implementing it](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/82).

Until then, you will need to use two declarations and a local binding, altough there's no need to clone the object:

```
import * as name from 'module';
export { name };
```

Comment: Oh, fantastic! That's exactly what I needed! I didn't realize you needed curly braces to do this, since MDN doesn't include them.

Comment: Where does MDN not use curly braces? Of course, in many other export declarations (defaults, vars, etc) they're not needed.

Comment: At the top of the page for the export statement, it lists the syntax for named exports as `export name1, name2, ..., nameN;` with no braces. Additionally, in the description, it gives this example: `export myFunction; // exports a function declared earlier`

Comment: Uh, those docs seem to be scarce. Better have a look at http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html (and I'll go fix MDN).

Comment: By the way, if you check and don't see the problem, it's because I just changed it. First time editing, hope I didn't mess up horribly.