# ES6 module syntax: is it possible to `export * as Name from ...`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

See question title. I found a [great reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34842087/718180) for the forms of `export` available, but I have not seen what I'm looking for.

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
// file: constants.js
export const SomeConstant1 = 'yay';
export const SomeConstant2 = 'yayayaya';

// file: index.js
export * as Constants from './constants.js';
```

I.e. this would provide a named export `Constants` inside of `index.js` containing all of the named exports from `constants.js`.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728140/is-it-possible-to-export-as-foo-in-typescript) seems to indicate it's not possible in TypeScript; is the same true for pure JavaScript?

(This example is a bit contrived; in reality I'm trying to have a `prop-types.js` module that uses named exports for internal use within the React package, but also exports the prop type definitions under `PropTypes` for external consumption. I tried to simplify for the sake of the question.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to export the result of “import * as” in ES2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33928698/1048572)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, it's not allowed in JS either, however there is [a proposal to add it](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from). For now, just use the two-step process with importing into a local variable and exporting that:

```
// file: constants.js
export const SomeConstant1 = 'yay';
export const SomeConstant2 = 'yayayaya';

// file: index.js
import * as Constants from './constants.js';
export {Constants};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I hope that makes it in.

Answer (score 30):

Today in 2019, [it is now possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

```
export * as name1 from …;
```

Answer (score 4):

The [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from) for this spec has merged to ecma262. If you're looking for this functionality in an environment that is running a previous JS, there's a [babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from) for it! After configuring the plugin (or if you're using ecma262 or later), you are able to run the JS in your question:

```
// file: constants.js
export const SomeConstant1 = 'yay';
export const SomeConstant2 = 'yayayaya';

// file: index.js
export * as Constants from './constants.js';

// file: component.js
import { Constants } from './index.js';

const newVar = Constants.SomeConstant1; // 'yay'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// file: index.js
// note, this doesn't have to be at the top, you can put it wherever you prefer
import * as AllExportsFromThisModule from "./index.js"; // point this at the SAME file
export default AllExportsFromThisModule;

export const SOME_CONSTANT = 'yay';
export const SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT = 'yayayaya';
```